# How to get webhook response data in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, api, webhooks

I've created an endpoint in my API than I'm going to use to use the webhook of Uber.
It is my first time working with webhook, so :
How I'm going to get the response they will give me by using my endpoint ?

Here what they will send to me (the datas bellow are for test):

```
{
    "event_type": "orders.notification",
    "event_id": "c4d2261e-2779-4eb6-beb0-cb41235c751e",
    "event_time": 1427343990,
    "meta": {
        "resource_id": "153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636",
        "status": "pos",
        "user_id": "89dd9741-66b5-4bb4-b216-a813f3b21b4f"
    },
    "resource_href": "https://api.uber.com/v2/eats/order/153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636",
}
```

And here my Api endpoint : (empty because I don't know how to handle it)

```
[HttpPost("/api/v1/.../delivery/hook")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(404)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> HookDelivery()
        {
            return Ok("hook reached");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When webhook event occurs, the source application typically triggers an http POST. So the easiest way is to create a C# representation of the JSON object you provided and use it as an input param fro your API method. Something like this:

```
public class WebHookData
{
   public string EventType {get;set;}
   public string EventId {get;set;}
   etc....
}
```

and then

```
    [HttpPost("/api/v1/.../delivery/hook")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExistTerminalSerialNumber(WebHookData webHookData)
    {
        // do something with your input here
        return Ok("hook reached");
    }
```

or something generic and have custom method that "converts" the incoming object to whatever you want it :

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExistTerminalSerialNumber([FromBody]JObject data)
{
    string eventType= data["event_type"].ToString();
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case "orders.notification":
                // do something
                return Ok();
            default:
                return BadRequest();
        }
}
```

Comment: I see and thanks for your reply. What if the WebHookData depend ? I can get a response also from Deliveroo and the result can be different. How do we manage this ? Using a Pattern ?

Comment: @harili sure, you can do whatever suits you best. you can also have a custom web-hook processing method per provider and thus use a completely different web hook object (in each method).